# Which of these database designs is normalized?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have two possible database designs.

A) a many-to-many relationship between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via a dedicated join table `FiscalYearsBranches`

B) two (or more) many-to-many relationships between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via other tables (`Documents`, `Factors`, etc.)

See the diagrams below. Which of these designs is better and why?

---

**Design A:**  a many-to-many relationship between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via a dedicated join table `FiscalYearsBranches`

---

[image]

---

**Design B:** two (or more) many-to-many relationships between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via other tables (`Documents`, `Factors`, etc.)

---

[image]

Comment: *Any* design that contains table names that have incremental numeric suffixes is most probably wrong (i.e. not normalized)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thay are only sample tables in this example

Comment: (a) **Neither** (b) You cannot Normalise or model anything when your starting point is to stamp an ID field on every file.  If you want to understand the data, strip the ID fields out, and tell us what the relationships are between the entities.  In words, not "fds".  We do not need a model at this early stage. (c) I can understand most of them from the names, except FiscalYears.

Comment: You need to know all the FDs and JDs to normalize, but to know that you need to know what the (natural language) membership criteria is for a row for each table.

Comment: @philipxy. You need FDs and JDs and MVDs and VDs for classroom exercises and puzzles related to what they teach as "relational theory" these days, using *a*'s and *b*'s and *c*'s.  Eg. to determine a "key" when it is not known.  That exercise will produce a non-relational record filing system, not a Relational Db.  That has little, if anything, to do with Normalisation as required for Relational Dbs, which is given in the *Relational Model*.  In real life, such as the question, the Keys are easily determined without the puzzle.

Comment: How many different fiscal years can one branch have?

Answer (score 2):

Assessing the normal form of a design is possible only if the sets of functional dependencies and join dependencies that apply to each individual table are given.

You haven't given those.